# Python qrcode not consistent

Tags: python, ubuntu, qr-code

I've got a very strange problem with [python-qrcode](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode).

I've had it working in our dev environment for a while now, without any issues. We use it to create two QR codes both of which contain URLs of almost exactly the same length (one contains an extra letter and two extra slashes). It's crucial that these two codes be exactly the same size.

Since we setup python-qrcode about five months ago, every single qrcode we have generated has been exactly the same size without fail. However, we've now pushed everything through to a production server and suddenly we have a problem.

Basically, one of the codes we generate is bigger than normal (this is the one with the three extra characters). The other code is the correct size. The two codes are generated using exactly the same function, we just pass the different URL to be encoded.

On my local machine and on our dev server, all the qrcodes are exactly the same size (including the one with the extra characters), but on the production server, the longer one is bigger while the other is correct.

We use Git version control, so all the files/functions etc are identical between the servers. The only difference between the setups is the version of Ubuntu (12.04 vs 12.10 on the production server), but I can't see why that would cause this issue.

If both codes were bigger, I could understand, but I can't work out why one would be bigger than the other on only one server.....?

If anyone can make any suggestion as to where to start working this out, I'd be very grateful!

EDIT:

Here's the relevant code:

```
myQrGenerator = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=QRCODE_SIZE,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
    box_size=QRCODE_BOX_SIZE,
    border=QRCODE_BORDER_SIZE
)

myQrGenerator.add_data('%s%s/' % (theBaseUrl, str(theHash)))
myQrGenerator.make(fit=True)
```

We get those variables from local_settings.py

Comment: When you say "size", do you mean the filesize of the resulting image?

Comment: Sorry - yes. The resulting image size, edge to edge.

Comment: Show the relevant code, please, i.e. how you're using python-qrcode's API.

Comment: If called via the default `make`, `python-qrcode` will [try to fit](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/master/qrcode/main.py#L45) the data, and possibly resize the image. Use `print_tty` to print the codes to screen to avoid PIL altogether, and rule out it misbehaving.

Comment: Also, what's the difference? One QR pixel in width and height? Several raw image pixels? Perhaps you can show the images themselves, too, and the strings encoded, so that we could try it out ourselves?

Comment: Will try that now, thanks soulseekah

Comment: The difference is that the image is 50 pixels (raw image pixels) larger in both dimensions

Comment: Are the QR pixels inside the same count, or are they just larger? If they are, looks like a PIL issue, although I can't yet imagine why and how. There are several variables being fed from above, in here https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/master/qrcode/image/pil.py#L10 perhaps you can step through that code on both machines to find out the difference in the variables and move up to the source of these variables.

Comment: The QR pixels are the same size - there are more of them in the incorrect code (and the layout is very different). Despite that, the codes both result in the same URL

Comment: So it doesn't seem to be a PIL issue if the QR boxes are of the same size, but there are more of them, PIL does what is says it does. I can assume that `print_tty` on the two machines yields the same behavior, wherein 12.10 produces a larger QR code (with more boxes) for the longer URL. And about "the codes both result in the same URL", let me get this straight, when scanning the codes do you get the same data back even if you fed in different data!?

Comment: I agree that it doesn't seem to be a PIL issue. You're going to have to help me out with the print.tty - I got an invalid syntax error. The "same URL" bit: when I feed in the same URL on the different servers, the production server returns a bigger QR code, but it contains the same URL as the code generated by the development server (which is the correct size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lengthy discussion it was established that the two servers used different URLs. The one that spewed out a larger QR code (in terms of QR pixels, and subsequently in terms of image pixels) overflowed, where the limit of bits it could store for the predefined size was not enough, and `qrcode` made it fit by increasing the amount of data it could store.

To fix this, `fit` was set `False` to provide a constraint for overflows, and `version` was increased to accomodate more bits from the start. `box_size` can be decreased a bit to maintain, more or less, the original image size.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a difference in the way [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is installed on the box. Looking at the [python-qrcode source](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/master/qrcode/image/pil.py), it does:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
except ImportError:
    import Image, ImageDraw
```

See what happens when you do:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
```

On each machine. Either way if it really isn't a bug in the application code (make doubly sure the same code is on each box), it sounds like it's going to be because of some difference in the way PIL builds itself on Ubuntu 12.10 vs 12.04, probably due to some different headers / libs it uses to compile. Look into ensuring the PIL installation consistent with the other boxes.

Comment: Thanks Purrell - presumably I need to be in a python shell? I got no response (error or otherwise) when I ran that in a python shell